# Create foreign key to the table itself with EF code first

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, foreign-keys

How can I build a tree-item class which contains a foreign key `fatherId` pointing to its father which in the same table?

Comment: [so] is a Q&A site, please read the help->tour. Although self answered questions are fine, the question has to be a question, i.e. something with a sentence that has a question mark. And not a blog post that only contains statements about things somewhat related to the implicit, and never asked question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
    [Table("LeveledItems")]
    public partial class LeveledItem
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        //Other columns.....

        public int? FatherId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("FatherId")]
        public virtual LeveledItem Father { get; set; }
    }
```